# Replace a string of the last 7 chars?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This is my code :

```
​var myStr = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png";​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and I'd like to replace the last 7 chars (`med.png`) with `big.png`. Or, as you can see, the last occurence after a `-` split.

How can I do it? I think about regex, but I'm not a champion with them. Tried :

```
myStr = myStr .replace(/-([^-]*)$/, "big" + '$1');
```

but it replace the last `-`, not the last occurence. So the result is `/private_images/last-edit/image-workbigmed.png`

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a great website to do regex...

Comment: why not use string functions - lastIndexOf("-")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex, or you could use a few string methods and make your intentions clear.

```
var idx = myStr.lastIndexOf("-");
var newStr = myStr.substring(0, idx) + "big.png";
```

Comment: @markzzz - Yeah there doesn't seem to be any difference between `substring()` and `substr()`, but if I'm wrong I'd love to know about it.

Comment: `substr(start[, length])` vs `substring(indexA [, indexB])` that's the difference :)

Comment: In this case, `start` and `indexA` are both `0`, so `length` and `indexB` are the same.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - Ah, thankyou. Probably not the best naming convention. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll make a confession: I'm not so great with regexes either.

How about splitting up using `split`? Less concise, but easier to understand.

```
var myStr = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png";​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
var strs = myStr.split('-');

// Change the last element.
strs[strs.length - 1] = "big.png";

// And put back the right string.
myStr = strs.join('-');
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `RegExp` you could use:

```
var str = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png"
   ,replace = 'big.png'
   ,nwstr = str.slice(0,str.lastIndexOf('-')+1)+replace;
//=> nwstr now "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-big.png"
```

More 'functional':

```
var nwstr = function(s){
              return s.replace(s.substr(-7),'');}(
               '/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png'
           )+'big.png'
```

Comment: Almost the same time, but yours is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png"; 
var index = url.lastIndexOf('-');
url = url.substring(0, index+1);
var url2 = "big.png";
var output = url.concat(url2); alert(output);
```

Check this

Answer (score 0):

Just add '-' to your regex and to the replacement string:

```
myStr = myStr .replace(/-([^-]*)\.png$/, "-big.png");
```

Or if you want the file extension to be variable:

```
myStr = myStr .replace(/-([^-]*)\.([a-z]+)$/, "-big.$2");
```

Comment: Is it better regex or lastIndexOf approch?

Comment: Better in terms of what? regex is more readable (at least to me). Performance is probably the same in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use replace:

```
var myStr = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png";​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

var newStr = myStr.replace("med.png", "big.png");
```

According to the requirements specified in your question this would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use string functions -

```
var myStr = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png";
var cleanedupStr = myStr.slice(0, myStr.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

[String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Answer (score 0):

If you know it will be a .png file:

```
var ex = new Regex(@"-\w*.png$");
var myStr = "/private_images/last-edit/image-work-med.png";​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
myStr = ex.Replace(myStr, "-big.png");
```

It works but if its a jpg it wont...